# (Unity 2d) Перемещение персонажа

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, touch-event

Когда пользователь проводит пальцем по экрану вправо, фиксирует палец, персонаж двигается вправо. Так же и с движением влево.
Вот код

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class scri : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 PointFromTouch()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
        Ray _ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.touches[0].position);
        RaycastHit _hit = new RaycastHit();
        float distance = 100f;
        Physics.Raycast(_ray, out _hit, distance);
        return _hit.point;
    }
    else
    {
        return new Vector3();
    }
}



     // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
{
    PointFromTouch();
}
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я провожу по экрану ничего не работает. Как можно это исправить?
Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Рейкаст ни с чем не столкнётся.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы тестируете этот код в unity при помощи мыши, то дело в том, что функция  `Input.touchCount` работает именно с тачами, а не с кликами мыши. Попробуйте использовать `Input.GetButtonDown` для дебага, или соберите Ваш проект в apk файл, запустите его на телефоне, и Вы убедитесь, что ваш if работает

Comment: Возникает ошибка: Assets\Script\scri.cs(9,13): error CS0019: Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'. Когда заменил Input.touchCount на Input.GetButtonDown.